# How to use Lambda in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying to query a table like `db.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID == id)` at:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var products = db.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID == id);
    return View("_ProductsFilterPartial");
}
```

but I am getting this error on `p.CategoryID` while the `CategoryID` is a column in the `product` table

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure that's your exact code that's throwing the error? I suspect you _actually_ have `.Where(p => p.CategoryID = id);` ( `=` instead of `==`) somewhere

Comment: Please include the error as text; search engines are not good at indexing text in images.

Comment: The compile-time error could be simply reproduced by using `=` instead of `==` in where clause in a linq query. So the first comment is definitely the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me you are using an assignment operator in a `Where` clause somewhere, like:

```
var products = db.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID = id);
```

The reason you get that error is because the `=` assignment operator *returns* the value that is assigned, so that you can chain assignments like this:

```
int i = j = 2;
```

So the result of `p.CategoryID = id` is a nullable int (since `id` is implicitly converted to a `int?` in order to be stored in `p.CategoryID`), so your lambda would take in a `Product`, *change* its `CategoryID` value, and return that value.  Therefore the type of the lambda is `Func<Product, int?>`, which cannot be implicitly converted to a `Func<Product, bool>` which is what `Where` requires.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this
`var products = db.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID.Value == id);`
And seem like you also forgot pass model to you view, maybe this
`return View("_ProductsFilterPartial", products);`
or use `ViewBag`, otherwise what's the meaning of this query.